# NSView draw permanently to background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to draw some things on the background of my windows. Therefore I subclassed the NSView of the window and added some drawing code like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    float color = 0.95;
    [[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:color green:color blue:color alpha:1.0] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(320, 0, 220, NSHeight(dirtyRect)-60));
}
```

This works great, but as soon as I open a NSComboBox or if I activate a checkbox, the background of these elements erases my just drawn rect.

I don't understand this, because checking for example the checkbox causes, that drawRect is called (I added a NSLog). Only resizing the window draws my rect again.

EDIT:
here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: call [view setNeedsDisplay] after the other UI elements are dismissed and you need to redraw the background

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this "solution" is insane. It causes a very ugly flickering and it's very inconvenient, because I have a) create for every element an IBAction and b) I have to put this line into this action.

Comment: Can you post some images of your exact problem and maybe we can find a better solution

Comment: What relation do the coordinates in your `NSRectFill()` call have to your view's bounds? Why are they not in fact computed *from* the bounds (e.g. with offsets or whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes face the same problem.  I think the following is what I use.

```
/// .h
@interface BackgroundView1 : NSView {
    NSImage *myImage;
}

// .m
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setupBackgroundImage];
}

- (void)setupBackgroundImage {
    NSColor *c = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0f/255.0f green:55.0f/255.0f blue:150.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    if (myImage == nil)
        myImage = [self createColorImage:NSMakeSize(1,1):c];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect { 
    [myImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect([self bounds].origin.x,[self bounds].origin.y,[self frame].size.width,[self frame].size.height)
               fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,[myImage size].width, [myImage size].height)
              operation:NSCompositeCopy
               fraction:1.0];
}

// Start Functions //
- (NSImage *)createColorImage:(NSSize)size :(NSColor *)color {
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                             initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                             pixelsWide:size.width
                             pixelsHigh:size.height
                             bitsPerSample:8
                             samplesPerPixel:4
                             hasAlpha:YES
                             isPlanar:NO
                             colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                             bytesPerRow:0
                             bitsPerPixel:0];

    [image addRepresentation:rep];
    [image lockFocus]; // Lock focus of image, making it a destination for drawing
    [color set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0,0,size.width,size.height));
    [image unlockFocus];
    return image;
}
// End Functions //
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great!
But please allow me one question: why do you use [myImage size].width instead of myImage.size.width? ;)

Comment: There's no difference.  The latter is the dot notation.  Microsoft's Visual Basic has the same.  I'm not sure if you need to select something in Xcode in order to use the dot notation.

Comment: Yes, I know that in this case there is no difference. But you could call the getter/setter method as well with the "." - I was just wondering, that you use both ways in one line without any obvious reason.

Comment: Hahaha...  I see.  Sorry...  I guess I didn't take a good look when you first asked as I read it during a sleepless night.  Yes.  You are right.  I should have kept the format throughout the implementation file.